# How to calculate distance between two locations and then display the way?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I need to calculate distance between two locations in my android application. Then I need to display the way on the map.

Looks like I need to use some Google API to calculate the distance. Should it be [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)? Android documentation [says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) that I should use Google Maps External Library, but I don't see there any method for the same. 
Probably, if I want just to calculate the distance between two points and not **walking** distance better to use some simplified approach.

Then to display the map - what is the advantage of usage of `MapView` compared with opening according url in user's browser? 
Would like to avoid the following actions:

> When you are ready to release your
>   application, you must register your
>   release certificate with the Google
>   Maps service and obtain a new Maps API
>   Key. You must then change the MapView
>   elements in your application to
>   reference the new API key.

Comment: are you looking for driving directions or just a straight line between the points?

Comment: There's no need to avoid getting an API key.  They are free and easy to obtain.

Comment: @wajiw, straight line. I've already found `location` module to calculate that. So, the only question I have now is about MapView vs. Browser. @Trott, I don't like the process that I should use one key for development and another key for release - so, I'll need to change the code for each release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance between two points can be found by using the equation described here:
http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Dist
remember, use radians, not degrees!

It seems you have concern about updating a maps key in each release? I have an app in the market that is map-based, and you get 1 prod key and 1 debug key (I believe it's per developer, but if not, it's per app). It has to do with the key you use to sign your apk. What I'm saying is that if you get your prod api key, and only ever develop this one app, you can publish many many updates without ever having to touch the key again (assuming you don't do debug-key testing locally).  If you're concerned about it, you can keep both in your AndroidManifext.xml file and just comment out the irrelevant one, depending on whether you're deploying to a device or emulator.

Answer (score 8):

You could also just do this:

```
//your two locations
Location locationA;
Location locationB;

//distance between them
float distanceBetweenPoints = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

bit late but hopefully this helps :)